# Why don't I need to add my main project's namespace in the test class files?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mstest

Hopefully an elementary question, but one to which I can't find an answer...

[This Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest#create-the-first-test) leads me to believe that I need to add a `using` directive for my main project's namespace to my test class files, in order to be able to access the main project's members.

```cs
using MainProject;

namespace MainProject.Tests;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTests
{
    ...
}
```

However, when I do so, Visual Studio Code (with the Microsoft C# extension) tells me the `MainProject` import is unnecessary. And indeed, my unit tests manage to access the main project members without the `using` statement.

Both the main project and the test project exist in separate directories and have separate `.csproj` files. Both live inside a parent folder containing an `.sln` file to which each has been added. The test project's `.csproj` file has a reference to the main project's.

The main project's namespace is: `MainProject`

The test project's namespace is: `MainProject.Tests`

I have opted into global usings in the test project file, and there is a `usings.cs` file, which contains one line:

```cs
global using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

Where is the magic happening? (For example, is there a rule that the "child" namespace automatically "inherits" the types declared in the parent?)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: "is there a rule that the "child" namespace automatically "inherits" the members of the parent?" - pretty much

Comment: However you're conflating the term "members" with "types" (_types_ contain _members_, and C# projects (generally) have only types as top-level _things_, as C# doesn't allow free-functions). Importing a namespace makes the _types_ in that namespace available, but you don't need to import a namespace to manipulate members of other types.

Comment: Thanks Dai! Wording corrected, as per your suggestion. Care to write an answer pointing me to documentation that explains `namespace MainProject.Tests` inheriting types declared in `namespace MainProject`, so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the official documentation explaining that namespace scopes "nest", and that the inner namespace has access to the members of the outer. Here it is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#77-scopes

(The second bullet point in section 7.7.1 describes the rule.)

When I last worked with C#, a long time ago, it was similar enough to Java to be virtually indistinguishable. But a lot has changed.

For example, I had forgotten that the Java-style namespace declarations are a recent addition to dotnet:

```cs
namespace MyCompany.MyProduct;
...
```

We used to have to do it like this:

```cs
namespace MyCompany
{
    namespace MyProduct
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Looking at it this way, it's easy to see why one might implicitly presume that the inner scope has access to the members of the outer, without having to read the rule from the language spec. If you're used to JavaScript scopes, for example, and your mental model of namespaces looks like the above, then the idea just seems natural.

However, if you're used to the way package imports work in Java, then this can seem very strange.

Answer (score 0):

A usising statement simple brings the namespace in scope for **name resolution**, it has nothing to do with directories or assemblies.

The namespace does the same thing, except it has a hierarchical basis and so isn’t as flexible.

In essence, there is no magic, you have misunderstood what is happening.

Comment: I think you're saying that `namespace MainProject.Tests` implicitly has access to `namespace MainProject`'s types. But if I issue a `using` statement that brings into scope a type with the same name as something in `namespace MainProject`, then the new type will "shadow" the `MainProject` type. Is that right? And the MS docs example explicitly imports the namespace `Prime.Services` because `Prime.UnitTests.Services` is NOT its direct "descendant".